# Synchronizing dependent asychnronized functions Objective C

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, asynchronous, objective-c-blocks

So I am running into a race condition and I have a few solutions on how to fix the issue. I am new to threading so obviously, my opinion and research is limited.  I have a large amount of asynchronization calls that can happen if a user receives certain messages from server.  Thus, my design is poor due to the dependent nature of my objects.

Lets say I have a function called

```
adduser:(NSString s){
does some asynchronize activity
}
Messageuser:(NSString s)
{
 Does some more asychronize activity
}
```

if a user were to recieve a message telling it to addUser "Ryan". he would than create a thread and proceed with looking up Ryan and storing him. However, if the user has the application in suspended mode, and in the buffered of messages waiting to be recieved there is a addUser request and a MessageUser request, a race condition occures because it takes longer to complete Adduser than it does to complete MessageUser.  Thus, If messageUser is called , and (in our example) "Ryan" has not been fully added, it throws an error.

What would be a possible solution to this issue.  I looked into locks and semaphores, and what I am trying to do is, when MessageUser recieves a call, check to make sure there is no thread currently proccessing addUser. If there is none, proceed. Else wait, than proceed after it has finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it depends on how the messages are being issued in the first place and what the async response events are.

If the operations have dependencies (ordering requirements) then perhaps a background serial queue would be appropriate? That is a simple way to ensure the messages are processed in order.

If the async operations take completion blocks, then you could have the completion block issue the request for the next operation to be performed, though you may not know about that ahead of time.

If you need to solve this in a more general way then you need some kind of system for tracking prerequisites so you can skip work items that don't have their prerequisites met yet. That probably means your own background thread that monitors a list of waiting tasks and receives notification of all task completions so it can scan for items waiting on that completion and issue them.

It seems really complicated though... I suspect you don't really have such strong async parallel processing requirements and a much simpler design would be just as effective. Given your situation where you are receiving messages from a server, I think a serial queue would be the best option. Then you can process messages in the order the server sent them and keep things simple.

```
//do this once at app startup
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.myapp", NULL);

//handle server responses
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    //handle server message here, one at a time
});
```

In reality, depending on how you connect to your server you might be able to just move the entire connection handling to the background queue and communicate with it via messages from the UI, and update the UI by dispatching to the dispatch_get_main_queue() which will be the UI thread.